# PHP CRUD, using Javascript (PostLink) to convert href $_GET link into a $_POST

Tags: php, jquery

I have a MySQL database with a PHP front end. Once the user's records are queried from the database, they are displayed in a table. I created a CRUD where the user can SELECT (to view additional details), DELETE, or EDIT. The CRUD uses Javascript up to the point that the client sends the query to the DB, then redraws the index page to reflect the changes in the DB.

I currently use a Javascript $_GET, but want to change it to a $_POST to hide the MySQL table id. I want to use something like [jQuery PostLink](http://code.google.com/p/postlink/). I only had a class in Java, I understand Javascript, but I am not thge best JS programmer.

Here is the script:

```
    <script src="http://postlink.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.postlink.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a').postlink();
      });
    </script>
```

Here is the PHP code that draws my table:

```
    foreach ($query as $row){
            $id =  $row['document_id'];
            echo ('<tr>');
            echo ('<td>' . $row [clientName] . '</td>');
            echo ('<td>' . $row [documentNum] . '</td>');
            echo "<td><a href='editDocument.php?tableau={$id}'>Edit</a>";
            echo " / ";
            echo "<a href='#' onclick='deleteDocument( {$id} );'>Delete</a></td>";
            // this calls Javascript function deleteDocument(id) stays on same page
            echo ('</tr>');   
    } //end foreach
```

I do not want to have to add form tage (`<form> </form>`) either. I want to call a script (like jQuery PostLink) that will work with the code that I have and convert href $_GET link into a $_POST. I want it to redirect to editDocument.php and have $_POST[tableau]=$id. I have been (unsuccessfully) trying to do this by "class:"

```
echo "<td><a class='postlink' href='editDocument.php?tableau={$id}'>Edit</a>";
```

I am having 2 problems with PostLink:

1. The example given converts all `<a>` to a $_POST (including the DELETE link).
2. The lack of documentation and sample code for PostLink.

Any thoughts???

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The reason I want to hid the ID is so that someone does not bookmark the page with "editDocument.php?tableau=59" and potentially cause problems if a record is restored. There is nothing that they can really get to since I am using PDO. I see that PostLink is old, that is why I was hoping for something else. I tried the changes that you suggested, I am still getting a redirect to "editDocument.php?tableau=59" Is there another tool that does what PostLink is suppose to do?

Comment: You should just use a form or use AJAX..  Scripts that turn links into POSTs just insert forms dynamically into the DOM and then call .post() on them...

Comment: @Stephen : That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to click a link, and redirect the browser with `POST` information without using a `form` tag, you are in a dead end.

You can `POST` using AJAX, but the page will return as an AJAX response. Your app would need to store the table ID in a session, this way the user can visit the page with no `GET` information and still see the correct information.

Comment: I want the script to turn links into POSTs just insert forms dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the code to select only the link you are interested in. If this is the HTML code:

   ```
   echo <a class='postlink' href='editDocument.php?tableau={$id}'>Edit</a>;
   ```

   You can change the Javascript snippet to this:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       $('.postLink').postlink();
   });
   ```
2. The plugin does not seem to be very used and is very old (2010). I would proceed with caution.

I would actually suggest to change your approach, if you really want to hide the table ID. Even if you change the code to fire a POST with javascript, anyone can just look at the network requests with some browser developer tool like Firebug.

One approach would be to change the MySQL table to store an extra key and change the PHP code to pass and accept the key as input. But the approach chosen depends on your specific implementation and use case.

Comment: I am not worried about the hacker looking at network requests, I am worried about the user bookmarking a page with a $_GET in the URL and causing issues with an record. I am trying to make this "stupid-proof."

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function editDocument( id, page ){
        var params = "edit_id=" + id;
        postOnClick( params, page );
    }
    function deleteDocument( id, page ){
        var params = "delete_id=" + id;
        postOnClick( params );
    }
    function postOnClick( params, page )
    {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        http.open("POST", page, true);

        http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        http.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                document.documentElement.innerHTML = http.responseText;
            }
        }

        http.send(params);
    }
</script>

<?php
    foreach ($query as $row){ 
        $id = $row['document_id']; 
        echo ('<tr>'); 
        echo ('<td>' . $row [clientName] . '</td>'); 
        echo ('<td>' . $row [documentNum] . '</td>'); 
        echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='editDocument( {$id}, 'editDocument.php' );'>Edit</a>"; 
        echo " / "; 
        echo "<a href='#' onclick='deleteDocument( {$id}, 'index.php' );'>Delete</a></td>";
        echo ('</tr>'); 
    }
?>
```

Example of links:

```
<a href='#' onclick='editDocument( 1, "editDocument.php" );'>Edit</a>
<a href='#' onclick='deleteDocument( 1, "index.php" );'>Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: what is the $_POST variable?  $_POST[delete_id] or $_POST[id]?

Comment: I used your script. I had to change the "EDIT" to redirect to edit.php. When I do `print_r($_POST);` (on edit.php) I get `Array ( ) ` returned.

Comment: when i test your case - all works normally. Show me your changes.

Comment: I used your first script and :
`foreach ($query as $row){
    $id =  $row['document_id'];
    echo ('<tr>');
    echo ('<td>' . $row [clientName] . '</td>');
    echo ('<td>' . $row [documentNum] . '</td>');
    echo "<td><a href='editDocument.php' onclick='editDocument( {$id} );'>Edit</a>";
echo " / ";
echo "<a href='#' onclick='deleteDocument( {$id} );'>Delete</a></td>";
// this calls Javascript function deleteDocument(id) stays on same page
echo ('</tr>');   
} //end foreach`

Comment: You forget change this attribute: `href='editDocument.php'` on `href='#'`

Comment: That `href='#'` is for the DELETE link. DELETE removes the record with an ALERT and reloads the index.php page (thus showing the table minus the record that was just deleted). EDIT link will redirect to edidDocument.php where I create a sticky form doing a query on the selected record where id = $_POST[id]. The user can then UPDATE which redirects and reloads index.php.

Comment: Tried it, it just stays on index.php#, it does not redirect to editDocument.php.

Comment: This script is not for redirect. He just sends the post data to a specific page and returns the response from it (this is what is known as AJAX). In our case - HTML. Now I'll try to find another way, but it will not be elegant.

Answer (score 0):

No way to do a post without a form tag.  You could use AJAX like this..  A more convoluted solution involves creating a dynamic form tag on the fly - but if you're doing that, why not just create the form in the first place...

Try something like this..

```
<a class='post_link' href='/action_url' data-action-id="12345">Delete</a>

And then

$(function() {
  $('.post_link').on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("action-id");
    $.ajax({
      method: 'post', 
      url: $(this).prop("href"), 
      data: {
        'id': id
      },
      success: function() {
        // reload the page or whatever - 
      }
    });

  });

});
```

If you're trying to avoid bookmarking, etc - it sounds like you'd be better served with better error handling on the backend side more than anything this is going to serve..

Comment: I just need to $_POST[id] = id; and redirect to editDocument.php. I will then use a query on editDocument.php to create a sticky form that can be updated via MySQL query.

Comment: So what this does is puts the id in the link as an HTML5 data attribute.  Then when you click on it, it will make the request a post instead of a get via AJAX..